# ionic scrolling header package issue in`building using `--prod` ( Please add a @NgModule annotation.)

Tags: angular, npm, ionic2, ionic3, angular5

There is a package in the git repo

https://github.com/keephacking/ionic-scrolling-header

which has every thing to make it compatible for aot . But while building my app with

`ionic build --prod` command , aot build fails with error shown below.

```
[18:02:48]  ngc started ...
[18:02:57]  typescript error
        Unexpected value 'ScrollingHeaderModule in
        xxx/node_modules/ionic-scrolling-header/scrolling-header.module.d.ts' imported by the
        module 'xxxModule in xxx/xxx.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule
        annotation.

Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
at xxx\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:237:55
at step (xxx\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:32:23)
at Object.next (xxx\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:13:53)
at fulfilled (xxx\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:4:58)
[18:02:57]  copy finished in 10.69 s
```

**My dependencies in Package.json**

```
{
   "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.1.1",
    "firebase": "^4.8.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "promise-polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.3",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.7",
    "typescript": "2.6.2"
  }
}
```

**Very curious to know whats missing in that package.**

**Thanks**

Comment: what's ur angular version ?

Comment: paste your `package.json`

Comment: Can you run `tslint` on the project and make sure it passes? Also try adding new line after the class export statement, parsers following POSIX can have trouble parsing lines not having a newline after it.

Comment: @sabithpocker you mean in my project right? yeah tslint runs without errors and tried with new lines after the exports .

Comment: How did you import the` ScrollingHeaderModule`

Comment: @Duannx, like all other modules .

Comment: Show it please!

Comment: `import {ScrollingHeaderModule} from ionic-scrolling-header`

Comment: @Duannx followed  usage info from https://github.com/keephacking/ionic-scrolling-header

Comment: Try this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15763#issuecomment-291577486

Comment: @Duannx , Iam using same version as the package is using.

Comment: Try to change your `package.json` to `"@angular/core": "^5.2.0"`. If it's still not working, there some other solutions in the issue i posted above

Comment: @Duannx nope nothing worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed in the latest version of ionic-scrolling-header package.

`npm install ionic-scrolling-header@latest` will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the below steps and it worked for me hope it helps you

Step 1: install `npm install ionic-scrolling-header --sav-dev`

Step2: Open Your `home.moduel.ts` file and import this `import {ScrollingHeaderModule} from 'ionic-scrolling-header';` and don't forget to add this inside your imports

```
imports: [
    ScrollingHeaderModule,
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage),
  ],
```

Step3: Inside your home.ts file add this `@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;`

Step 4: inside your home.html page add this `<ion-header [scrollingHeader]='content'>`

For more information check this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-scrolling-header)

Comment: Yes but i believe its because of third party plugin

Answer (score 1):

I have fixit with follow steps:

```
0-Download project from author repository
1-Rename "src" folder to "ionic-scrolling-header", and copy to your directive(folder)
2-Create a directive folder inside src (folder)
3-Change import in your app.module.ts, as you can see on my print:
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0xnw.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this error when my tsconfig.json wasn't emitting the declaration files.

Be sure you have the following in the tsconfig.json in the codebase that builds `ScrollingHeaderModule`:

`"declaration": true,`

Comment: The package has all these https://github.com/keephacking/ionic-scrolling-header, you can it .

Comment: Yes, this is true - I only commented on this as I recently bumped into it while investigating a similar problem my side. Apologies that it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

**Ionic 6.7.0 , Corodova 0.14.0**

Faced similar issue, tried everything....later figured out that i was missing import of Class 'XYZ' in file **directives.module.ts**. So added import statement in that file and also, in NgModule declaration.

```
import {ParallaxHeader} from './parallax-header/parallax-header';
@NgModule({
declarations: [ParallaxHeader],
imports: [],
exports: [ParallaxHeader] })
```